# How do you import the timestamp type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am having problems to import the standard `timestamp.proto` in node.js.

```
// Some abc.proto file
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
...
...
```

When doing something like this:

```
var grpc = require('grpc');
var protoDescriptor = grpc.load('abc.proto');
```

I expect grpc to get the timestamp.js from the installation directory but this is not the case.

How do you import the timestamp type in node.js.

I have a local grpc install (npm)? I would prefer to avoid passing paths, etc. In fact, the grpc node.js package does not seem to be deploying the standard proto files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been opened as an issue in the corresponding repo 
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13010

It seems to be a known limitation at the moment.